# BIRT reverses the order of columns when generating XLSX

Tags: eclipse, birt, eclipse-mars

I have a BIRT report that works fine when exporting to HTML or using the web view, but when I make an excel file all the columns are reversed. The column that should be rightmost is all the way on the left and vice versa. I also had some weird issues in the Eclipse editor, where "insert a column to the right" would add one to the left (which then did end up becoming the right when exporting to Excel).

I'm using BIRT 4.5.0 on Eclipse Mars.

Comment: You should post a .rptdesign  based on the "classic model" sample database and showing the problem, because this issue seems specific to your report: in my case the column order is correct when exporting to XLSX  with all reports i tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Report Orientation" was set to "Right to Left" for some reason, which was not uniformly recognized by the different output types. After setting it to "Left to Right" my report now generates as displayed.